# I am getting extra row in asp gridview, How to solve this?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to hardcode asp:gridview and retrieve one column from the DB and display it on Grid View.
But when I am displaying, it gives me 2 columns, Where first one  is just dummy and the other consists of the actual  data which I want to display.

The Code which I wrote is here :

```
<asp:gridview ID="gvEmpnames" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderText" Text="EmpID" /></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderText" Text='<% eval("eid") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Comment: What is showing up in the additional row? the name of columns? post the result please

Comment: are you getting row or column?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set AutoGenerateColumns false (which is default true).

```
<asp:gridview ID="gvEmpnames" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderText" Text="EmpID" /></HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderText" Text='<% eval("eid") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

[system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, focusing on best practices, I encourage you to separate Layout items from code. Gridview generates a table, layout this table with CSS.
(In `border-width` you don't need to use "px", as all attributes with Width units in ASP controls)

Second, your gridview core code can be improved giving you more readability and understanding of your code (maintainability).

Finally, a common error in showing unwanted additional rows in Gridviews is forgetting to hide the Auto generated columns.

```
<asp:gridview ID="gvEmpnames" runat="server" CssClass="grid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="eid" HeaderText="EmpID" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```